# What is the meaning of content and backward slash in css

Tags: html, css, css-content

I have downloaded a site with a site downloader, which had nice icons on it. But after downloading it, that icons went away and I cannot see any image file.

In html, it's like this.

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="buttons.html">
      <i class="icon-up"></i> Buttons
   </a>
</li>
```

the class looks like below.

```
.icon-up:before {content: "\f0a6"; }
```

What is the meaning of that class definition's

```
:before
content
```

and

```
"\f0a6"
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out where the icons went? It's probably using an icon font that's somehow not loading correctly in the downloaded site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google really helps.

`content` denotes a real content that's put inside a css element. So, `p:before {content: 'hello'}` would put a string `hello` in front of the paragraph content. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gRjRe/

The content you shown (`"\f0a6"`) is just a Unicode value for a font character. See how they are used here, for example: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: Technically, `\f0a6` refers to Unicode code point U+F0A6, which is a Private Use code point. No character is assigned to it by the Unicode standard, but it may be used by agreements between interested parties; so it is a “character” only if you make a special agreement on that. Font Awesome violates the principle that Private Use code points should not be used in public information interchange.

Comment: +1 They are violating them too often, I wouldn't be surprised if it becomes a standard soon.

Answer (score 1):

It outputs the character with Unicode value `f0a6` (61606) before any element with class `icon-up`. As Shomz pointed out via [this link](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/), it's a hand pointing upward in this context.

Answer (score 1):

```
.icon-up:before {content: "\f0a6"; }
```

**Explanation:**

- `:before` is before each matched/found `.icon-up` element
- `content` is the content to introduce *before* each `.icon-up` element, in your case, it is a Unicode value f0a6 (61606), which generated by [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) as a vector icon:

  [image]

**Definition:**

- The `:before` selector inserts content before the content of the selected element(s).
- The `content` property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

Answer (score 0):

tag:before{content:value}

means put the value of content before the tag

and "\f0a6" means hand up icon

in your case a handup icon will shown before the list Buttons